not able to import lottie library which I want to add some animation to my flutter app .The command I am using :import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
While using the lottie animation for the first time I encountered a problem which was while importing the lottie library . I am using the command import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart'; but on using it , it says that this does not exist . What should I do ? I think like while writing programs in other languages we have to download the libraries but also I do not know how to do that .
Please help me and tell me the problem because no one is explaining the problem regarding the imports

this question is solved as I expected just entered the command dart pub add lottie
and the problem was solved

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can follow the installation instructions:
https://pub.dev/packages/lottie/install
In order to use the package as a library, you need to add it as a dependency. To do this, you can run
flutter pub add lottie
in your command line.
Only after that can you import the package accordingly.
Hope it helps!
